# Decode Apk, open Eclipse Auto-Save Data?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, restore, workspace

Just yesterday eclipse gave me following error:
"an error has occurred. see the log file"

I searched the internet about what to do, and tried this solution:
http://bugsanddebugs.blogspot.de/2010/06/when-eclipse-says-error-has-occurred.html
Basically:" i deleted:  /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources "

After that I could open up Eclipse again, my whole workspace was gone though.
Because that didnt work, i put the deleted file back into place. So my workspace is just like it used to be now. Now i can open eclipse, but it does not load any projects into itself. It is plain empty

The big problem was however, that i saved my latest project only to an apk file which i cannot acces now.
I tried decoding it with the apktool and apktool-install-windows-r05-ibot.tar. The folder i get out of it is corrupted tho. The xml files are not in the right shape and the src code is in smali files.

But there must be another solution I believe. 
Before the incident, i could open eclipse and all my projects where there, even though i never saved them in their latest state. 
So where does eclipse save those projects? Can I somehow do a backup and tell eclipse to load my old workspace? 
I did not change the path eclipse uses as its workspace, but it is not loading anything in there. Eclipse is just plain empty when i open it now. In my folder org.eclipse.core.resources I can see all my projects listed, but when i go deeper there is only .indexes, .org.eclipse.jd.core, .loctation, .markers in there.

I would be so happy if any of you could help me. 
Greetings, Marvin.

Comment: `Can I somehow do a backup...` Backups must be done **before** something happens, not after. If you deleted your workspace and you have no backup, thre's nothing you can do. You can have different workspaces and choose which one to use. `The xml files are not in the right shape` They are **compiled**.

Comment: Eclipse stores your files where you tell it to. Probably in your workspace? You might want to browse it outside of Eclipse though since you've deleted config files for Eclipse.

Comment: I did not delete anything in my workspace. After deleting /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources , I put it back into my workspace. So my workspace is just like it was yesterday. Eclipse does not load anything from it in tho

Comment: I am not sorry to say this.  I have no sympathy with anyone who puts effort into creating software and does not have effective (and tested) backups.